# JComboBox appears inactive on Windows 10 but items can be selected

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a strange issue related to swing application. The behavior of two `JComboBox` elements is really disturbing when testing it on two different operating systems.

On Windows 7 everything works smooth and the combo boxes appear active and I can select items. However when I test it on Windows 10 (same version of the application) the combo boxes are grayed out but I still can select items no matter that they look inactive.

Is this some kind of bug?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Do you have a code snippet of the JComboBox init command or pictures the behaviour is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is more related to the Look&Feel you are using. which L&F you are using?

Try to set the combo box as inactive and compare the UI. I assume that it looks different.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the comment!
Here is the L&F I use:
`[The Microsoft Windows Look and Feel - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel]` Keep in mind it is same in both cases win 7 and win 10